# Does an IMAP store always have an INBOX?

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap

I'm using JavaMail's IMAP Store.

When opening the inbox, is it safe to assume that the name is always called "INBOX"?

```
IMAPFolder folder = (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("INBOX");
```

Or is the "inbox" name nothing special and on a Swedish IMAP server it could be called "inkorg"?

I guess this same question applies equally to IMAP in general, beyond JavaMail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Additionally, according to [RFC 3501: INTERNET MESSAGE ACCESS PROTOCOL - VERSION 4rev1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-5.1), INBOX has a number of special behaviors to boot:

5.1.    Mailbox Naming

> The case-insensitive mailbox name INBOX is a special name reserved to
> mean "the primary mailbox for this user on this server".  The
> interpretation of all other names is implementation-dependent.

6.3.3.  CREATE Command

> It is an error to attempt to create INBOX or a mailbox
> with a name that refers to an extant mailbox.

6.3.4.  DELETE Command

> It is an error to attempt to delete INBOX or a
> mailbox name that does not exist.

6.3.5.  RENAME Command

> Renaming INBOX is permitted, and has special behavior.  It moves
> all messages in INBOX to a new mailbox with the given name,
> leaving INBOX empty.  If the server implementation supports
> inferior hierarchical names of INBOX, these are unaffected by a
> rename of INBOX.